# Powershell import-csv with tilde delimited file

Tags: powershell

I can't seem to get the syntax correct for using the powershell cmdlet import-csv with a '~' (tilde) deliminted file.  I've tried

```
import-csv file.txt -Delimiter ~
import-csv file.txt -Delimiter "~"
import-csv file.txt -Delimiter '~'
import-csv file.txt -Delimiter `~
import-csv file.txt -Delimiter '`~'
```

Here's what i get if i use the first line

```
 Import-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run
 the operation again.
At line:1 char:11
+ Import-Csv <<<<  .\file.txt -Delimiter ~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

I assumed it was the '~' but maybe it's not.  I just replaced all the '~' in the text file with ',' and get the same error

Comment: the first line works for me, can you show the same data? Does the column header also use ~ as the column header delimiter?

Comment: All lines except the last worked for me (last one fails, because within single quotes the backquote is a literal backquote, not an escape character). How exactly do these not work for you? How is the result you get different from the result you expect? Do you get an error? If so, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

It was a file header issue.  Because import-csv file.txt -Delimiter , worked, i incorrectly assumed it was a problem with the command line, but with more digging i realized i needed to specify the -header parameter and it worked.